# Using \left and \right in math mode, but the display is not satisfied

Tags: amsmath, output, parentheses

I intended to use `\left` and `\right` command to display large parentheses in my paper, but the output is not exactly what I wanted.

The output is 
[image]

as can be found, the parentheses and square bracket in above and below are not in a uniform scale.   What I wanted is
[image]

That is, the parenthesis `right )` and square bracket `right ]` shall have the same size as the corresponding above ones. How can I solve it?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
(P_k^i)^{-1}
& \geq \sum_{j\in \mathcal{N}} \pi_{L,k}^{i,j} \alpha_{k-1}  F_{k-1}^{-T} \;(P^{j}_{k-1})^{-1} F_{k-1}^{-1}\notag\\
&\quad+ \sum_{j\in \mathcal{N}} \pi_{L,k}^{i,j}  (H_k^j)^T (R_k^j)^{-1}H_k^j  \notag\\
 & = \alpha({k-2},k)  \left[ \sum_{j\in \mathcal{N}} \pi_{L,k}^{i,j}  (F_{k-1}^j)^{-T}\left( \sum_{o\in \mathcal{N}} \pi_{L,{k-1}}^{j,o}\right. \right.\notag\\ 
 & \quad  \times \left. \left. (F_{k-2}^o)^{-T}  (P^{o}_{k-2})^{-1} (F_{k-2}^o)^{-1} \right) (F_{k-1}^j)^{-1}\right] \notag\\
  &\quad + \alpha_{k-1} \left[ \sum_{j\in \mathcal{N}} \pi_{L,k}^{i,j}  (F_{k-1}^j)^{-T}\left( \sum_{o\in \mathcal{N}} \pi_{L,{k-1}}^{j,o}\right. \right.\notag\\  
 & \quad  \times \left.\left. (H_{k-1}^o)^T (R_{k-1}^o)^{-1}H_{k-1}^o  \right) (F_{k-1}^j)^{-1}\right] \notag\\
 & \quad + \sum_{j\in \mathcal{N}} \pi_{L,k}^{i,j} (H_k^j)^T (R_k^j)^{-1}H_k^j
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW: There is really no reason for the fences around the sums to be that large.

Comment: It looks clear, and it's very convenient to check the proof procedure.

Comment: Not really, it takes up too much space and draws attention to itself, which is a bad thing while reading.

Comment: Well, it depends. You have the point, but from my viewpoint, a better layout is important for the peer review.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of the cases which tell you that `\left` and `\right` constructs are better be avoided. You can use `\Bigg` from `amsmath`. For details, see `amsldoc`, page 18, section 4.14.1.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
(P_k^i)^{-1}
& \geq \sum_{j\in \mathcal{N}} \pi_{L,k}^{i,j} \alpha_{k-1}  F_{k-1}^{-T} \;(P^{j}_{k-1})^{-1} F_{k-1}^{-1}\notag\\
&\quad+ \sum_{j\in \mathcal{N}} \pi_{L,k}^{i,j}  (H_k^j)^T (R_k^j)^{-1}H_k^j  \notag\\
 & = \alpha({k-2},k)  \Biggl[ \sum_{j\in \mathcal{N}} \pi_{L,k}^{i,j}  (F_{k-1}^j)^{-T}\Biggl( \sum_{o\in \mathcal{N}} \pi_{L,{k-1}}^{j,o} \notag\\
 & \quad  \times  (F_{k-2}^o)^{-T}  (P^{o}_{k-2})^{-1} (F_{k-2}^o)^{-1} \Biggr) (F_{k-1}^j)^{-1}\Biggr] \notag\\
  &\quad + \alpha_{k-1} \Biggl[ \sum_{j\in \mathcal{N}} \pi_{L,k}^{i,j}  (F_{k-1}^j)^{-T}\Biggl( \sum_{o\in \mathcal{N}} \pi_{L,{k-1}}^{j,o} \notag\\
 & \quad  \times  (H_{k-1}^o)^T (R_{k-1}^o)^{-1}H_{k-1}^o  \Biggr) (F_{k-1}^j)^{-1}\Biggr] \notag\\
 & \quad + \sum_{j\in \mathcal{N}} \pi_{L,k}^{i,j} (H_k^j)^T (R_k^j)^{-1}H_k^j
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\Bigg` and friends, you don't need to have the matching in the same line.

Comment: Besides, the syntax of it is much easier than using `left` and `right`, since you needn't to define the a null `left.` or `right.`, when break a large equation.

Comment: `\Bigg` is too big; better `\bigg`, in this case. Also use `\biggl(\,` with a thin space when a summation with a wide subscript follows

Answer (score 5):

The problem appears because the `\right]` is paired with the corresponding `\left.`, and sized according to what appears between the two. It does not try to resize according to what was in the previous line, because it is a totally different expression to him.

If you want the lower brackets to be the same size as the ones above, you have to trick them into thinking that their content is as large as the one above.

You can achieve that using the command `\vphantom`: it creates an empty object with the same height as its argument.

As already mentioned in the comments of the other answer, the syntax is more inconvenient than manually sizing the delimiters. At that cost, the delimiters will automatically resize to accomodate changes of content (if you maintain the content of the `\vphantom` as well).

Here is a (simplified) example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Without \verb|\vphantom|:
\begin{align*}
  E = & \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{a^{b^{c}}}{i^{i}} \right. \\
  & \left. + 2 \right]
\end{align*}

With \verb|\vphantom|:
\begin{align*}
  E =& \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{a^{b^{c}}}{i^{i}} \right. \\
  &\left. + 2
   \vphantom{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{a^{b^{c}}}{i^{i}}} % I just copied the first line into the vphantom
  \right] 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, the solution is great and impressive. I wish I could accept two answers.